# Images not displaying in the react.js

Tags: reactjs, image, react-bootstrap

I am trying to render the images in React.js as a card content but it does not show the image.
[image]

The code to display image:

```
const Template = ({ template }) => {
  console.log(template.preview_image)   // <- It displays the image path
  return (
    <Card className="my-3 p-3 rounded">
      <Link to={`/template/${template._id}`}>
        <Card.Img src={template.preview_image} variant="top" />
      </Link>

      <Card.Body>
        <Link to={`/template/${template._id}`}>
          <Card.Title as="div">
            <strong>{template.name}</strong>
          </Card.Title>
        </Link>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

The `template` prop coming from the following code:

```
  {loading ? (
    <Loader />
  ) : error ? (
    <Message variant="danger">{error}</Message>
  ) : (
    <Row>
      {templates &&
        templates.map((template) => (
          <Col key={template._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
            <Template template={template} />
          </Col>
        ))}
    </Row>
  )}
```

The useEffect function:

```
  const templateList = useSelector((state) => state.templateList);
  const { error, loading, templates } = templateList;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listTemplates());
  }, [dispatch]);
```

The images are also saved at the server side in the uploads folder.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you show the code where you send the `template` and import the image?

Comment: @Tehila I don't understand `where you send the template` and I am not importing image from anywhere.

Comment: Your `template` variable is coming from the props, so where do you call this 'Template' component and send the image you want to it?

Comment: Is there something in the console? Maybe these resources are blocked, e.g. by CORS

Comment: @Tehila I have updated the question please go through it.

Comment: @zaxanq There is no error in the console.

Comment: This is quit weird. Are you sure you get the right location in the console?

Comment: @Tehila Yes, the images are saved in the folder called uploads in the src directory on the server side. for example: ```src\uploads\preview_image-1665133802206.jpg```

Comment: The location of the image should be according to the component where you use it - `Template`. If your `Template` is inside the `src/components` folder for example, then the location should be: `..\uploads\preview_image-1665133802206.jpg`

Comment: @Tehila I don't think this is the problem and I have tried moving the image file to many different locations in my project but that still doesn't work. If I am doing wrong please enlighten me.